# Page count of an email

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I want to get the page count of the email. I am using Outlook as my email client.

I am able to get the body of the message, but not sure how many pages it has .

Comment: How do you define "pages"? Word count? How many pages it would be when printed? In that case, it would completely depend on the layout of the page, which format you would print it in, and other printer settings. In other words: there would be no way to determine this.

Comment: Email messages don't have the concept of a number of pages. An attachment, like an MS-Word file, might.

Comment: i see page number as disabled option in outlook !!

Comment: You want to know how many pages the email would be if it were printed or something?

Comment: @JamesJohnson - thats exactly I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email has no page count per se - think of it as one single page with an unbound page height. A page count in the common sense of the word comes into existence, when the mail is printed, exported as a PDF. or in any other way transformed onto a paged medium. The page count in this case will depend on medium width and height, margins etc.

If you need the page count for printing, you will have to look into print preview.

Comment: Eugene, how do I transfer it to a paged medium. I want to print the email to a PDF, for that I need to know the page count, to add the number of pages to the PDF. How do I know the number of pages.

Comment: The page count is only available AFTER you created the PDF - so you need to do it twice (Count pages on first pass)

Comment: Can you please elaborate. How do I get the first pass.

Comment: You use whatever tool you plan, to create the PDF, substituting "xxx" for the page count. This gives you a PDF, from which you get the page count (or your tool gives this info back directly). Then you run again, this time with the correct page count.